# Rails - Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Users who bet on matches. A single bet is called "Tipp" and the users predict the match score in "tipp.tipp1" and "tipp.tipp2"

I have problems with my form which is supposed to save "tipps" of users.

With the code below I get "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tipp" although i have set "accepts_nested_attributes_for :tipps" and "attr_accessible :tipps_attributes".

I hope I have provided all the necessary code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the parameters output:

Parameters:

```
{
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mPPpCHjA3f/M2l1Bd3ffO1QUr+kdETGkNE/0CNhbJXE=",
 "user" =>{
          "tipp"=>{
                    "6"=>{"tipp1"=>"4","tipp2"=>"6"},
                    "7"=>{"tipp1"=>"-1","tipp2"=>"-1"},
                    "8"=>{"tipp1"=>"-1","tipp2"=>"-1"}
                  }
            },
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "user_id"=>"1"
}
```

Shortened Code:

Controllers:

1) Users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def edit_tipps
    @user = current_user
end

def update_tipps
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:notice] = "success (maybe)"
        redirect_to user_edit_tipps_path(@user)
    else
        flash[:error] = "errors"
        redirect_to user_edit_tipps_path(@user)
    end
end
```

Models:

1) Users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :tipps_attributes

has_many :tipps
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tipps
end
```

2) Tipps

```
class Tipp < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :match_id, :points, :round_id, :tipp1, :tipp2, :user_id

belongs_to :user
end
```

My Form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => "update_tipps" }  do |user_form| %>
    <% @user.tipps.each do |tipp| %>
    <%= user_form.fields_for tipp, :index => tipp.id do |tipp_form|%>
        <%= tipp_form.text_field :tipp1 %><br/>
        <%= tipp_form.text_field :tipp2 %><br/>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_or_cancel(user_form) %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing what you did,
you could try either:

1.
Instead of:

```
  <% @user.tipps.each do |tipp| %>
  <%= user_form.fields_for tipp, :index => tipp.id do |tipp_form|%>
```

I would do this:

```
  <%= user_form.fields_for :tipps do |tipp_form| %>
```

Or:
2.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :tipps_attributes, :tipps
```

Goodluck